# Unix Universe ODBC .net query show one column (ID) only

Tags: unix, universe

I know it's all database system. Hopefully i can get some help here. Thank you

We recently try to use ODBC and .net toolkit provided by rocketsoftawre to retrieve the data from the universe database.

The problem we encountered is.

1) Some table we are able to list out all the column. But some table only show one column of record even though that particular table has more than one column

Preview for table with all column show
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoDol.png

Preview for table with single column show
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSsTC.png

Answer (score 0):

Someone needs to go into the Universe side and clean up the dictionaries on the files you want to view from ODBC. You can either convert them to SQL tables, which I find is a process fraught with peril, or you can add a type "PH" dictionary item on each table called "@SELECT" and list out all of the fields you would like to make available when executing `SELECT * FROM TABLE;`

Having clean well defined dictionaries is the key to interoperability between universe and the outside world.